# DOMException: Could not start video source

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to run the webRTC code which i have mentioned below, it is working fine when i am connecting with two devices using same network. But it is not connecting when the devices are in different networks and i am getting DOM Exception. please help me to fix it.

[please refer the below link for your understanding](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ScaleDrone/webrtc/master/script.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a TURN-Server. (CoTurn for example). The traffic will be relayed if a direct connection is not possible (NAT, Firewall,...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: we added the TURN server but still we are getting this error              DOMException: Failed to set local answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable please do needful

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963787/failed-to-set-local-answer-sdp-called-in-wrong-state-kstable